# Remove the button if there are no elements SwiftUI

Tags: button, swiftui

Please help me I can't disable the button if there is no element in the array. I want the button not to appear in the absence of an element. I know what needs to be applied .disabled but I can't implement it yet

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestModel {
    var text: String?
    var ansver: [String]
    var correctAnswer: String?
}

var test: [TestModel] = [
    
TestModel(text: "one", ansver: ["one", "two", "three", "four"], correctAnswer: "one"),
                                
TestModel(text: "five", ansver: ["five", "six", "seven", "eight"], correctAnswer: "five"),

TestModel(text: "nine", ansver: ["nine", "ten", "twelve"], correctAnswer: "nine") // 3 values 
]
```

If you remove one value ansver:["nine", "ten", "twelve"] / Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var i: Int = 0
    @State var score = 0
    //@State var scoree = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if(self.i < test.count) {
                Text(test[self.i].text!)
                
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                    self.buttonAction(n: "")
                }, label: {
                    Text((test[self.i].ansver[0]))
                    
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .background(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                                .stroke(Color.blue,lineWidth: 2)
                        )
                })
                Button(action: {
                    self.buttonAction(n: "")
                }, label: {
                    Text((test[self.i].ansver[1]))
                    
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .background(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                                .stroke(Color.blue,lineWidth: 2)
                        )
                })
                Button(action: {
                    self.buttonAction(n: "")
                }, label: {
                    Text((test[self.i].ansver[2]))
                    
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .background(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                                .stroke(Color.blue,lineWidth: 2)
                        )
                })
                
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.buttonAction(n: "")
                        
                }, label: {
                    Text((test[self.i].ansver[3])) // Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .background(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                                .stroke(Color.blue,lineWidth: 2)
                            )
                    
                       })
                
            }
        }
        .padding()
        
    }
    func buttonAction( n: String){
        if(test[self.i].correctAnswer == n) {
            self.score = self.score + 1
        }
        self.i = self.i + 1
    }
    
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I tried to do it through nill, but nothing happened.Hi guys.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is to hard-code the number of buttons which crashes because there are four buttons but only three possible answers in the last item of the array.

The solution is a loop, but first of all declaring the struct members optional is pointless. They have always a value, and they are constants (`let`)

```
struct TestModel {
    let text: String
    let answers: [String]
    let correctAnswer: String
}
```

In the view replace the buttons 2 to 4 with a `ForEach` loop

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var index = 0
    @State private var score = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if index < test.count {
                Text(test[index].text)
                ForEach(test[index].answers, id: \.self) { answer in
                    Button(action: {
                        buttonAction(answer)
                    }, label: {
                        Text(answer)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .padding()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .background(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                                    .stroke(Color.blue,lineWidth: 2)
                            )
                    })
                }
            } else {
                Text("Finished with score: \(score)")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func buttonAction(_ answer: String){
        if answer == test[index].correctAnswer {
            score += 1
        }
        index += 1
    }
}
```

Side note: Rather than iterating indices I recommend to iterate the questions and answers.

Comment: Thank you Vadian, for helping me a lot! Thanks.